# Packaging node-webkit for windows on mac

Tags: node-webkit

I developing an application using node-webkit. But I'm developing using OSX but need to distribute for Windows and I need it to be .exe as end users would not have terminal access or node installed.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you use something like [wine](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) or [parallels](www.parallels.com) then install windows in it(long process but it might be worth it).

Answer (score 0):

Use [nw-builder](https://github.com/nwjs/nw-builder)

You will also need Wine installed to associate the .ico icons with the application

Answer (score 0):

I (like many others) use [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to build the exe files on Mac. To get started, use [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and [generator-node-webkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-node-webkit) for a basic project layout.

Than, making win executable (or mac) is easy as:

```
grunt dist-mac
grunt dist-win
```

Let me know if you need any more info.